# What does the error JSX element type 'Header' does not have any construct or call signatures" mean?

Tags: javascript, jsx, semantic-ui-react

I wrote this code and the error is showing at Header and List. It keeps saying that JSX element type Header does not have any construct ....?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Header, List } from 'semantic-ui-react';


function App() {
  const [admin, setAdmin] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/admin').then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      setAdmin(response.data);
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <Header as='h2' icon='users' content='Reactivities'/>     
          <List>
          {admin.map((AppUser: any) => (
            <List.Item key={AppUser.id}>
              {AppUser.city}
            </List.Item>
          ))}
          </List>
          </div>
  );  
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Does *semantic-ui-react* export those two things? Did you log their values in your code and confirm that they're actual components?

Comment: Yes, I did but still it isn't working

Comment: The`import` syntax is consistent with [semantic-ui-react docs](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/header/#types-page), so the problem is elsewhere. 

Can you share your dependencies ? Are you using a framework like `create-react-app` ?

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with the same error for a pretty long time. Finally, the reason for me was an incompatibility of versions. It got fixed with this combination:

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"semantic-ui-react": "^2.1.2"
"@types/react": "^17.0.3",
"@types/react-dom": "~17.0.3"
```

Comment: For React 18, it's so far possible to apply a workaround by recasting from `React.StatelessComponent` to `React.ElementType`. Example: `const _Header = Header as unknown as React.ElementType` (or something similar).